Expo app.config.ts: Pick Xcode "Supported Destinations"
New to Expo and migrating an older react native white label app to 0.76.
I am almost done setting up the app.config.ts but I have trouble finding how to pick Supported Destinations for Xcode. It would be so sweet if we can do complete clean prebuild and not even need to check in the native folders any more!
It's an iPhone only app but we run it on Mac Catalyst for development so we want to remove iPad and add Mac Catalyst. Extra points if we can set the default target to "My Mac". Thanks!

